# JMapping - category_icon_options

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I've been working with the JMAPPING jquery plugin for a while and something changed with  the Google API (I think) because the category icon options no longer seems to work. This stopped working about 2 weeks ago and I never changed my ASP code. Even the [example #5](http://vigetlabs.github.com/jmapping/examples/category_options.html) on the JMAPPING website does not display the color of the icons correctly.

The markers all display on the maps, but they are all Red. The Red marker is the last marker in the record set that matched a specific category in the category_icon_options section of the JAVASCRIPT.

Anyone else have this issue?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="map-side-bar">
<div class="map-location" data-jmapping="{id: 154157499, point: {lng: -82.70809000, lat: 28.03966000}, category: 'Green'}">
<a href="#" class="map-link">Green 12:00:39 0MPH</a>
<div class="info-box">
  Unit:69@3/31/2013 9:15:33 AM<br>
  Elapsed Time: 12:00:39<br>
  Speed: 0MPH<br />
</div>
</div>

<div class="map-location" data-jmapping="{id: 154158127, point: {lng: -82.74336000, lat: 28.14920000}, category: 'Red'}">
<a href="#" class="map-link">Red 12:12:03 7MPH</a>
<div class="info-box">
    Unit:69@3/31/2013 9:26:57 AM<br>
    Elapsed Time: 12:12:03<br>
    Speed: 7MPH<br />
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#map').jMapping({
            map_config: {
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 12
            },
            category_icon_options: {
                'Green': { color: '#008000' },
                'Yellow': { color: '#FFFF00' },
                'Red': { color: '#FF0000' }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vendor will fix the JS in the future, no fix now. I decided to move to full Google MAP API v3 and not us a 3rd party JS tool.
Thanks
Jim